# Chernoff-like bound for largest allowed deviation?

Tags: probability

Chernoff bound (for [absolute error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Theorem_for_additive_form_.28absolute_error.29)) gives a bound on probability of large deviation in terms of sample size and amount of deviation, but it doesn't seem possible to rewrite it to give an explicit bound on the amount of deviation. So, what is good way to bound the largest deviation from the mean in terms of sample size and probability of that deviation?

Comment: deviation from the mean of what? what are the assumption on your random variable or what type of bound do you need (exponential?). I think your question would be easier to answer if you could formalize it a bit more and if you add some details. take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory

Comment: Hm...I thought it was unambiguous given that I'm talking about Chernoff bound for absolute error...added a link in question (it seems to break in comment)...in that notation, I'm looking for epsilon as a function of m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in that notation, I'm looking for epsilon as a function of m

If I have not misunderstood, this indicates you want to solve an equation in $q~ (= p +\epsilon)$ of the form

$$q \log(p/q) + (1-q) \log((1-p)/(1-q)) = D(q\,\Vert\, p) = y;\ y \lt 0,$$

given $p$ and $y.$  ($y = \log(p)/m$ reveals the $m$-dependence.)

It is correct that we do not have a name for the solution, but that does not mean it cannot be found, and fairly easily at that.  A little algebra converts this equation into one of the form

$$H(q) = \alpha + \beta\,q$$ where

$$H(q) = -q \log(q) - (1-q) \log(1-q) $$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depend only on $y$ ("probability of deviation") and $m$ ("sample size").

Geometrically this asks for the intersections of a concave downward curve and a line; the curve has endpoints at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ and is symmetric in the unit interval.  There will therefore be up to two solutions.  Newton-Raphson ought to converge rapidly after an initial set of bisection steps finds a point between 0 and the left root and another between the right root and 1 (assuming either exists).

If you need them, theoretical properties of the solution(s) could be readily derived from the definitions of $H,$ $\alpha,$ and $\beta.$

Comment: Yes, it looks like it needs to be solved numerically in general. I really just needed a practical way of plotting epsilon as a function of n, and ended up using a version of Chernoff inequality for fair coin from which expression for epsilon can be obtained in closed form

Answer (score 0):

I will try and answer your question for only one of the bounds. Chernoff bounds are given by:

$$Pr\left[\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{i=m} X_i \ge p+\epsilon\right] \le e^{-D(p+\epsilon\Vert p)m}$$

where

$D(\cdot )$ is the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback-Leibler_divergence)

For the sake of convenience I will denote the rhs of the above inequality by $r(p,\epsilon,m)$. Thus, we have:

$$Pr\left[\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{i=m} X_i \ge p+\epsilon\right] \le r(p,\epsilon,m)$$

The above can be re-written as:

$$Pr\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{i=m} X_i \ge m\ (p+\epsilon)\right] \le r(p,\epsilon,m)$$

If we let: $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{i=m} X_i$ then we know that:

$$Y \sim \textrm{Binomial}(m,p)$$

where

$p = Prob(X_i=1)$

Given the above it follows that,

$$Pr\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{i=m} X_i \ge m\ (p+\epsilon)\right] = Pr\left[ Y_i \ge m\ (p+\epsilon)\right]$$

But,

$$Pr[ Y_i \ge m\ (p+\epsilon)] = \sum_{k=\lceil m\ (p+\epsilon) \rceil}^{k=m} {m \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}$$

Thus, it follows that:

$$\sum_{k=\lceil p+\epsilon \rceil}^{k=m} {m \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k} \le r(p,\epsilon,m)$$

I am not sure if we can simplify the above to express $\epsilon$ as a function of $m$ but it may be of some help. Alternatively, you may want to explore the use of the normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the point of derivations

Comment: Perhaps, I misinterpreted what you wanted. Did you not want to express $\epsilon$ as a function of $m$? The above does not exactly get you there but I thought it is a start towards that goal.

Comment: Yes, as function of $m$ and $P$. Since $P$ is given, it doesn't make sense to rewrite it

Comment: Oh, I understand.